# Checkbox in TVirtualStringTree is not updating properly when OnChecking opens a MessageBox

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

When checking or unchecking the checkbox in the vst, I want to ask for confirmation in some cases.
(Un)checking works fine until I open a `MessageBox` from the `OnChecking` event handler.

When I have shown the `MessageBox` (and set `Allowed` to true) the checkbox state does not change and I have to click a second time in order to toggle the checkbox.

For any reason I haven't figured out yet, the second time the `OnChecking` event handler isn't called.

It seems to be related with the focus: if I click on another node before the second click to the checkbox it doesn't work a all. I'm using Delphi XE2 and Vitual Treeview 5.3.

Can somebody confirm this behavior and think of a fix/workaround?

This MCVE shows the behavior. Just add a button and a vst to a form and assign the event handlers:

```
type
  TMyData = class
  public
    value: String;
    constructor Create(str: String);
  end;

constructor TMyData.Create(str: String);
begin
  value := str;
end;

procedure TForm3.btnInitTreeClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  VirtualStringTree1.NodeDataSize := Sizeof(TObject);
  VirtualStringTree1.TreeOptions.MiscOptions := VirtualStringTree1.TreeOptions.MiscOptions + [toCheckSupport];
  VirtualStringTree1.CheckImageKind := ckSystemDefault;

  with VirtualStringTree1.Header.Columns.Add do
  begin
    Text := 'Colum header';
    Width := 150;
  end;

  VirtualStringTree1.AddChild(nil, TMyData.Create('1')).CheckType := ctCheckBox;
  VirtualStringTree1.AddChild(nil, TMyData.Create('2')).CheckType := ctCheckBox;
  VirtualStringTree1.AddChild(nil, TMyData.Create('A')).CheckType := ctCheckBox;
  VirtualStringTree1.AddChild(nil, TMyData.Create('B')).CheckType := ctCheckBox;
end;

procedure TForm3.VirtualStringTree1Checking(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode; var NewState: TCheckState; var Allowed: Boolean);
var
  data: TObject;
begin
  data := TObject(Sender.GetNodeData(Node)^);
  if assigned(data) and (data is TMyData) and (TMyData(data).value = 'A') then
    Allowed := Application.MessageBox('Are you sure?', 'Confirmation', MB_YESNO or MB_ICONQUESTION) = ID_YES
  else
    Allowed := true;
end;

procedure TForm3.VirtualStringTree1GetText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex; TextType: TVSTTextType;
  var CellText: string);
var
  data: TObject;
begin
  data := TObject(Sender.GetNodeData(Node)^);
  if assigned(data) and (data is TMyData) then
    CellText := TMyData(data).value
end;
```

**Edit**: The problem also can be reproduced with version 5.5.2

Comment: Have you tried using the latest XE2 compatible version [5.5.2](https://github.com/Virtual-TreeView/Virtual-TreeView/releases/tag/V5.5.2) or the [XE2 fork](https://github.com/Virtual-TreeView/Virtual-TreeView-XE2)?

Comment: @JoachimMarder no I haven't as I did not find an entry in changelog or issues.

Comment: I can't tell from my mind if this is a known issue. Is there anything that prevents you from using the latest available version?

Comment: I should not change component version on my development machine just for testing purposes. I will try it on a testing / "play" machine (probably on Monday or Tuesday) and let you know the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm this behavior. VST v4.5.5

The problem with the `OnChecking` implementation (`TBaseVirtualTree.HandleMouseDown`) is that the `WM_LBUTTONUP` message is not being processed and `TBaseVirtualTree.HandleMouseUp` goes out of sync when showing the modal dialog, and the new state is not being updated. I have not dug deep enough into this to suggest a general fix.

**The workaround:**

```
type
  TBaseVirtualTreeAccess = class(TBaseVirtualTree);

procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTree1Checking(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode; var NewState: TCheckState; var Allowed: Boolean);
var
  data: TObject;
begin
  data := TObject(Sender.GetNodeData(Node)^);
  if assigned(data) and (data is TMyData) and (TMyData(data).value = 'A') then
  begin    
    Allowed := False; // We will handle this ourself
    if Application.MessageBox('Are you sure?', 'Confirmation', MB_YESNO or MB_ICONQUESTION) = ID_YES then
    begin
      // Update the state and trigger OnCheck if needed
      TBaseVirtualTreeAccess(Sender).DoCheckClick(Node, NewState);
    end;
  end
  else
    Allowed := True;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Same behaviour on *5.2.1*.

The following does the job modifying the state **after** it's changed.

```
procedure TForm3.VirtualStringTree1Checked(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode);
var
  data: TObject;
begin
  data := TObject(Sender.GetNodeData(Node)^);
  if assigned(data) and (data is TMyData) and (TMyData(data).value = 'A') then begin
    if Application.MessageBox('Are you sure?', 'Confirmation', MB_YESNO or MB_ICONQUESTION) = IDYES then
      Exit;
    if  Node.CheckState = csUncheckedNormal then
      Node.CheckState := csCheckedNormal
    else
      Node.CheckState := csUncheckedNormal;
  end;
end;
```